# Google Apps Script - Javascript not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a simple web app, and it is not working.

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {//I think this works
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
  output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  output.setTitle('email button');
  return output;
}

function getContent(filename) {//might work
  Logger.log('getContent()');  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('javascriptCode').getRawContent();
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="email_subscribe">
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
      <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
    <?!= getContent("javascript") ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

javascriptCode.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitButton").onclick(function() {
      alert('thx for submitting');
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I run this webApp, the email and button fields load properly, and the logger logs 'getContent()'. However, nothing happens when I click the button. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In your index.html, when you call getContent you passed in javascript and not javascriptCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite few errors in your code.

1. Script tag is not a self closing tag.
2. It is safer to serve https version of jquery, sometime http content
   will be blocked.
3. There is **NO** onclick event in jquery it is just **click**.

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
  output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  output.setTitle('email button');
  return output;
}

function getContent(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="email_subscribe">
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
      <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?!= getContent("javascriptCode") ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

**javascriptCode.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
      alert('thx for submitting');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## A Simple HTML dialog example

I usually test these things as a dialog to get them working.  It's works as a dialog and I've also included the doGet. I hope this helps.  I didn't go exactly as you were going but I think this will help you move that way.

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() 
{
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('webappdoesnotwork');
  return output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}

function getEmail(email) 
{
  Logger.log(email);
  return true;
}

function showDialog()
{
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('webappdoesnotwork');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(output, 'My WebApp');
}
```

webappdoesnotwork.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      function getEmail()
      {
        var email=$('#email').val();
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(sayThanks)
          .getEmail(email);
      }
      function sayThanks()
      {
        $('#saythanks').css('display','block');
        $('#controls').css('display','none');
      }
      console.log('My Code');
    </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="saythanks" style="display:none">Hey Thanks for Responding</div>
        <div id="controls">
          <input type="text" id="email" size="35" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
          <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit" onClick="getEmail();"/>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is inline javascript allowed in google apps script?

Comment: Yes.  The dialogs can look pretty much like any other html file with the one notable exception that asynchronous callback handlers are dead simple compared to standard javascript or even JQuery. By the way, you can still use the onClick  property of the html input tags.  And be careful when assigning click functions.  Be sure to unbind unused click assignments if you try to change them while dialog is running.