# How do I return a value from a google script gs file to the html form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet script with 2 files (funcs.gs and userForm.html)

In HTML file in one function I call:

```
var progName = google.script.run.getProgramName(data[1]);
console.log("myProgramName = " + progName);
```

In the getProgramName function in funcs.gs, I have

```html
function getProgramName(progName){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Courses");
    var p = ws.getRange(2,1,9,3).getValues();

    for(var i=0; i< p.length; i++){
        if(p[i][0] == progName){
            Logger.log("found progName = " + p[i][2]);
            return p[i][2];
        }
    }
}
```

So, in the Logger, I do see "found progName = CGEC-HVAC" when this is called, but back on HTML, the value is not being displayed in the console log

```
 userCodeAppPanel:121 myProgramName = undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

MK

Comment: It has to be requested from the html. So you could poll for it.

Comment: In this case `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getProgramName(data[1]);` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: are you aware you need a trigger function,the most common being `doGet`?

Comment: Even if I use google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getProgramName(data[1]);, I still get undefined...

Comment: as for doGet, I am just using the sidebar, not a full on web app

Comment: How did you implement the SuccessHandler if you passed it something with a restricted data type then that doesn't work. Check the restrictions in the guides section of the documentation.

Comment: You can use  with an anonymous function like this: `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){}).getProgramName();`

Comment: If you're still having trouble then provide [mcve].  It's hard to figure out what you doing with just a few incomplete snippets

Comment: Maybe this example will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987108/7215091

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Google Apps Script - Javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45985938/1595451)